# Can I get a Google user identify from their access_token?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Implementing Google OAuth in Firebase Cloud Functions.

Everything is working but I have a weird issue. Everything is working, but **I don't know how to identify the user to save the tokens to** their user object in Firestore.

Using the google API nodejs library, I create an authURL using the OAuth2 client, set the scopes etc, then redirect the user to it. This works great.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
  YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
  YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);

const scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
];

const authorizationUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
    access_type: 'offline',
    state: 'state_parameter_gets_passed_back',
    scope: scopes,
    // Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
    include_granted_scopes: true
  });
console.log('created an authorizationUrl: ' + authorizationUrl);
res.redirect(authorizationUrl);
```

I then have an https Cloud Function endpoint set as the redirect URL, waiting for the response.

When it comes I get the code and request the tokens. This also works great, until I get to `saveUserToken`. **Who is the user?** My Cloud Function is just listening to responses

```
exports.recieveGoogleCodeFromResponseURL = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {     
  const code = req.query.code;
  console.log('got a code, it is:' + code);

  const url = require('url');
  if (req.query.code != null) {

    let userCredential;
    console.log('we have a code, trading it for tokens');

    let { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
    console.log({ tokens });
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
      
//THIS IS THE PROBLEM HERE, who is the user to save the tokens to?
    saveUserToken(tokens, uid); //saves to Firestore
  }

  res.json({result: `Got a response from Google`, code: code, scope: req.query.scope});
});
```

The response looks like this:

```
{
access_token: "longtoken",
expiry_date: 166...,
refresh_token: "anothertoken",
scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
token_type: "Bearer"
}
```

From what I understand neither the access_token or refresh_token is JWT token I could decode to get user info.

All of the Firebase Cloud Functions examples I have read from Google say something like 'In production you would save this token to a secure persistent DB', which I can do with Firestore. I just can't figure out how to ID the user the callback and code belongs to.

All the code samples that show OAuth with other services (Instagram, LinkedIn, Twitch) either the results come with the user id, or their API allows you to query the service with just the access_token and get the user.

For example in this Login with Instagram example the response comes with the user Id.
Code here > https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/instagram-auth/functions/index.js

```
const oauth2 = instagramOAuth2Client();
const results = await oauth2.authorizationCode.getToken({
        code: req.query.code,
        redirect_uri: OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI,
      });
      functions.logger.log('Auth code exchange result received:', results);

        // We have an Instagram access token and the user identity now.
const accessToken = results.access_token;
const instagramUserID = results.user.id;
```

In this OAuth example from LinkedIn, once again they pass the access token to a LinkedIn endpoint to identify the user. Code here https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/linkedin-auth/functions/index.js

```
const linkedin = Linkedin.init(results.access_token);
linkedin.people.me(async (error, userResults) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  functions.logger.log(
    'Auth code exchange result received:',
    userResults
  );

  // We have a LinkedIn access token and the user identity now.
  const linkedInUserID = userResults.id;
```

I can use [this Google library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) to validate an ID token, but I am not getting an ID token back from the OAuth process.

Feels like I am missing something simple. Is there a Google API I can pass an access_token to to identify the user?

Answer (score 1):

The `access_token` returned by Google OAuth is not a JWT. It's an opaque string that is only meaningful to Google, and that you can use to identify the user with Google APIs.
You can use the Google People API to get information about the user. With the `access_token` you can query the Google People API and get information about the user

Answer (score 1):

Sh_ghosa's answer sent me down a misleading rabbit hole so I'm providing this answer to protect your time that I've spent for you.

The following code example uses the NodeJS Google Cloud SDK and therefore assumes that the GoogleAuth module is provided in the language you're using.

```
  // libraries (npm)
  const {google} = require('googleapis');
  const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

  // business logic
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
  });
  const authClient = await auth.getClient();
  const accessToken = await authClient.getAccessToken();
  const decodedJwt = jwt.decode(accessToken?.res?.data?.id_token);
  const principal = decodedJwt?.email; // <:: the principal
  console.log('Who am I?  ', principal);
```

Comment: To be clear, the access token IS a jwt and you decoded it to get the email etc?

Comment: @JoshuaDance Good clarifying question. That is quite the tricky part. In the response, the literal property `token` is related, I think, to `Sh_gosha`'s answer. Looking further within the response payload, you'll find a property `id_token`. That `id_token` property IS a JWT and that is what I decoded to get the information. 

Here's a source code reference I found: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/main/src/auth/oauth2client.ts#L331

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

## Ask for additional scopes

At first I was just asking for Google Calendar permissions.

```
const scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
```

The trick is to ask for `email`, and `profile` as well,

```
const scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar email profile'
```

If you ask for these additional scopes, Google sends back an `id_token` with the `access_token` and the `refresh_token`

You can get the user email and other information from that id_token.

You can decode the token locally since it came from a secure https session with Google and you check that the `state` variable passed back matches the one your system generated.

```
function decodeIdTokenLocally(token){
  //we split the id_token at the period ., and just decode the 2nd part
  let secondPart = token.split('.')[1];
  let localUserJsonString = atob(secondPart);
  let localUser = JSON.parse(localUserJsonString);
  return localUser
}
```

Quick note - Asking for more than 1 scope at once gives this ugly checkbox interface where users have to manually click the checkboxes of the scope you are asking for.

Better to have them Login With Google first, which grants the email and profile scopes, then ask for Calendar scope or additional scopes one at a time which will present the nice one click to accept interface.

I haven't tried @sh_gosha suggestion of sending the `access_token` to the Google People API but I think that would work as well, but it would add an additional API call.